# Not getting a reading from my ESP32 from my soil moisture sensor

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, esp32

Using an ESP32 I am attempting to collect data from my HW-390 Capacitive soil moisture sensor. 
However when I run the code on the ESP32 it doesn't give any values.

```
>>> import pythonsoil6
>>>
```

I think I need to add a print command but I don't know exactly what I need to do. Could someone look over my code and tell me what the problem is.  PS: Written on a raspberry pi using the Thonny IDE.

```
from machine import ADC, Pin

adc = ADC(Pin(32))          # create ADC object on ADC pin
adc.read()                  # read value, 0-4095 across voltage range 0.0v - 1.0v

adc.atten(ADC.ATTN_11DB)    # set 11dB input attenuation (voltage range roughly 0.0v - 3.6v)
adc.width(ADC.WIDTH_9BIT)   # set 9 bit return values (returned range 0-511)
adc.read()
```

Comment: replace `adc.read()` with `print(adc.read())`. But please pick up a python book (any python book) to learn some basic python language.